# What is the data format for the device address using libMPSSE I2C?

Tags: ftdi

I am attempting to use [libMPSSE to perform I2C communications](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_177_User_Guide_For_LibMPSSE-I2C.pdf). The example code listed in the attached document connects to a [24LC024H](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22102a.pdf) EEPROM device.

The address for the device used in the example as defined in it's documentation is `1010XXX_` where the `X`'s are configurable. In the examples associated diagram you can see the values are configured to be `1`. It also states that the R/W bit (`_`) should not be included meaning the address passed to the library should be `10101110`. The address actually used in the example code is `0x57` which is `01010111`.

I do not see how we got from A to B here. I cannot figure out how to format the address of the device I am trying to communicate with nor can I find any documentation spelling it out. The only documenation on the address parameter says:

> Address of the I2C slave. This is a 7bit value and it
>   should not contain the data direction bit, i.e. the
>   decimal value passed should be always less than 128

This confusing since the data direction bit is usually the LSB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was updating my question to clarify what the address should be and a coincidence in the editor cause the answer to smack me in the face.

By "should not be included" they do not mean that the bit should be zero but rather by completely nonexistent. To them this means shifting the address bits down to remove it as the LSB. It also implies that the MSB should always be zero even though it's not explicitly defined anywhere.